# i upgrade my laravel application 5.6 to 5.8 and now when i can try to create new route it's not working

Tags: php, laravel

i upgrade my laravel application 5.6 to 5.8 and now when i try to create new route it's not working is there anybody here to told me what the main problem and why it not working the route it say 404 not found

thanks 
Juwel

Comment: What do your route file(s) look like?

Comment: Share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Run this command

```
    composer update
    php artisan config:clear
    php artisan route:clear
    composer dumpautoload -o
```

Comment: Hi, I am using lumen. I am having the same issue. after upgrade, new routes are not working. config:clear and route:clear are not supported. How can I make it work?